# Is it faster to use iterator-based search-and-use in STL associative containers?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

Let's say I'm trying to check if an item exists in an associative container, and do something to it if it does. The simple way to do this is as follows:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Whatever> thisIsAMap;

// C++17
if (thisIsAMap.count("key") > 0u) { doThing(thisIsAMap["key"]); }
// C++20
if (thisIsAMap.contains("key")) { doThing(thisIsAMap["key"]); }
```

However, this has always seemed somewhat wasteful to me, as it involves finding the same item twice, which might be quite an expensive operation. Instead, I tend to do this:

```
auto found = thisIsAMap.find("key");
if (found != thisIsAMap.end()) { doThing(found->second); }
```

This only requires finding the item once, and then using it.

Is the latter approach actually any better? Are there any good reasons to use either approach over the other?

Comment: Have you tried profiling both approaches, to see which one is fastest? This is something that you should be easily able to figure out yourself.

Comment: Why ask a question when you've already answered it yourself?

Comment: Dear people leaving comments: OP is not asking about  `count` vs `contains`, as would be obvious if you actually read the question. OP is asking about using `count`/`contains` and then `[]` vs using `find`.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili `contains` is _exactly_ like `count` for a `map` or `unordered_map` where `count` only can return `0` or `1`.

Comment: @Barry Oops I didn't see that he's actually doing a second search to find the value, in which case 1 search is better than 2 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is the latter approach actually any better?

Yes. For several reasons.

First, doing one `map` lookup is definitely at least as fast as doing two `map` lookups. Best case, the compiler optimizes out the second lookup, but I've never actually seen that happen in practice and that seems like a lot to rely on.

Second, using `find` means you only have to type `"key"` once, rather than twice, which just reduces a potential source of error.

Third, using `[]` requires the value type to be default constructible - so in addition to being worse for performance and software engineering reasons, it also can add more requirements to your type that you may not be able to meet.

Fourth, it's just more obvious from a code-reading perspective that you're looking up an item and then using that item if it's found... rather than looking up an item and happening to look up the same item again.